# Java EE JDBC Realm cannot login?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jdbcrealm, payara

Hi I've been trying to get this thing up for a long time now. I've got a payara 4.1.1 application server running and I tried to create a realm, but I cannot login to my webpage. It always says that:

```
Severe:   jdbcrealm.invaliduser
Warning:   WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception
```

I'm running mySql server Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16.

I tried to google like a madman, but I didn't get closer to the solution.

[image: webxml]

[image: jdbcRealmconfig]

Comment: [sqltable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL8nh.png)
[jdbc connection pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdFFG.png)
[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKaZO.png)

stackoverflow didn't let me include more than 2 links in my post.

Comment: I am also having this problem. Did you find any solution.

Comment: Yes, payara 4.1.1 had a bug. Changing to glassfish 4.1 worked fine.

Comment: I had copy paste issue which was resolved by http://stackoverflow.com/a/40834951/2532694